# How to get ens username using ensjs

Tags: javascript, ethereum, ethers.js

On the [ensjs README](https://github.com/ensdomains/ensjs), I see this code snippet:

```
import ENS, { getEnsAddress } from '@ensdomains/ensjs'



const ens = new ENS({ provider, ensAddress: getEnsAddress('1') })

ens.name('resolver.eth').getAddress() // 0x123
```

However, when I add that snippet to my webapp, like this:

```
const ens = new ENS({ provider, ensAddress: getEnsAddress('1') });
const name = ens.name('resolver.eth').getAddress();
name.then((str) => {
  console.log(str); // this is another hash, not my .ens username
});
```

My dev console logs another `0x...` hash, not my .ens username

How do I get my username using this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
    const address = await signer.getAddress();
    const ensName = await provider.lookupAddress(address);
```